# How to change HTML form with 2 selections to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, post, mod-python

I am working with the following HTML form:

```
<form method = 'POST' action = '/python/stats/'>
<select name = 'team'>
<option value = 'team1'> team1 </option>
<option value = 'team2'> team2 </option>
<option value = 'team3'> team3 </option>
</select>
<select name = 'player'>
<option value = 'player1'> player1 </option>
<option value = 'player2'> player2 </option>
<option value = 'player3'> player3 </option>
</select>
<input type = 'submit' value = "Update">
</form>
```

The action /python/stats requires 2 parameters.  How can I edit this form (to javascript?) so that the action is called each time either of the selects is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `action` property in the form tag specifies the location to `submit` the form to. To do this with an `onchange` event is, you can do a form submit in the event.

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function doSubmit(){
    document.forms["form1"].submit();
}
</script>
</head>


<form id='form1' method = 'POST' action = '/python/stats/'>
<select name = 'team' onchange='doSubmit();'>
<option value = 'team1'> team1 </option>
<option value = 'team2'> team2 </option>
<option value = 'team3'> team3 </option>
</select>
<select name = 'player' onchange='doSubmit();'>
<option value = 'player1'> player1 </option>
<option value = 'player2'> player2 </option>
<option value = 'player3'> player3 </option>
</select>
<input type = 'submit' value = "Update">
</form>
```

Comment: The onchange handler can be simply: `this.form.submit();`. But submitting a form using the select's onchange is not user friendly. If navigating with the cursor keys, IE will fire a change event every time a key is pressed so users will not get past the first option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- I was able to get it working, with the line 'document.form1.submit();' changed to 'document.forms["form1"].submit();'